# C# - Iterate through all members of a group using graph.api graphClient.Groups. Compiler error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to follow this C# example at this link which Iterate over all the messages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp

I have applied that paging to something similar to instead iterate through members that belong to a group and the code is throwing an error on the return true; line of all places.  Can anyone help me understand why I get the error:

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Here is the code:

```
 
                var members = await 
                 graphClient.Groups[groupObjectId].Members.GetAsync(requestConfiguration => 
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999;  
                    
                });                
                var pageIterator = PageIterator<Group, GroupCollectionResponse>
                    .CreatePageIterator(
                    graphClient,
                    members,
                    // Callback executed for each item in
                    // the collection
                    (m) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Group ID: {m.Id}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Group Name: {m.DisplayName}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Group Description: {m.Description}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Group Created Date Time: {m.CreatedDateTime}");

                        //count++;
                        return true;
                    },
                    // Used to configure subsequent page
                    // requests
                    (req) =>
                    {
                        // Re-add the header to subsequent requests
                        req.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"");
                        return req;
                    }
                );

                await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the query returns `DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse` not `GroupCollectionResponse`. So, you need to modify the `PageIterator` and for each item check if the item is either `User` or `Group`

You don't need to configure subsequent page request (adding header `req.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"")` makes sense only for messages as it is in the example)

```
var pageIterator = PageIterator<DirectoryObject, DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse>
            .CreatePageIterator(
            graphClient,
            members,
            // Callback executed for each item in
            // the collection
            (m) =>
            {
                if (m is User user)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {user.Id}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"User Name: {user.DisplayName}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"User Created Date Time: {user.CreatedDateTime}");
                }
                else if (m is Group group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Group ID: {group.Id}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Group Name: {group.DisplayName}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Group Description: {group.Description}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Group Created Date Time: {group.CreatedDateTime}");
                }

                //count++;
                return true;
            }
        );
```

You can even cast the response to the group

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups[groupObjectId].Members.GraphGroup.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
             {
                 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999;

             });
        var pageIterator = PageIterator<Group, GroupCollectionResponse>
        .CreatePageIterator(
        graphClient,
        groups,
        // Callback executed for each item in
        // the collection
        (m) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Group ID: {m.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Group Name: {m.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Group Description: {m.Description}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Group Created Date Time: {m.CreatedDateTime}");

            //count++;
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: How did you know that?  This is the first time I've tried to create code to do this and also use the graph api calls.  How did you know to use DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse vs GroupCollectionResponse.

Comment: @bmickey I've tried the same code in Visual Studio and found out that graphClient.Groups[groupObjectId].Members.GetAsync returns DirectoryObjectCollectionResponse

Comment: You are correct, I just didn't understand that.  I really appreciate your help!